# Better solution to MySQL nested select in's

Tags: mysql

Currently I have two MySQL tables

Properties

```
id    name 
1     Grove house
2     howard house
3     sunny side
```

Advanced options

```
prop_id    name
1          Wifi
1          Enclosed garden
1          Swimming pool
2          Swimming pool
```

As you can see table two contains specific features about the properties

When I only have max 3 options the query below worked just fine. (maybe a little slow but ok) now things have expanded somewhat and i have a max of 12 options that it is possible to search by and its causing me some major speed issues. The query below is for 8 options and as you can see its very messy. Is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to achieve?

```
SELECT * FROM properties WHERE id in (
select prop_id from advanced_options where name = 'Within 2 miles of sea or river' and prop_id in ( 
    select prop_id from advanced_options where name = 'WiFi' and prop_id in ( 
        select prop_id from advanced_options where name = 'Walking distance to pub' and prop_id in ( 
            select prop_id from advanced_options where name = 'Swimming pool' and prop_id in ( 
                select prop_id from advanced_options where name = 'Sea or River views' and prop_id in ( 
                    select prop_id from advanced_options where name = 'Pet friendly' and prop_id in ( 
                        select prop_id from advanced_options where name = 'Open fire, wood burning stove or a real flame fire-place' and prop_id in ( 
                            select prop_id from advanced_options where name='Off road parking') 
                        ) 
                    ) 
                ) 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

Comment: Are you trying to query for a record in `properties` that has ALL the `advanced_options` you are querying on?

Comment: HI Mike, Yes that is correct.

Comment: Are there any max number a property can have (practically)?

Comment: Hi Michael, I wouldnt have thougt that there will be more than 6 but the customer thinks they need 12 so i would imagion it should never go above 20! but i wouldnt hold my breath.

Comment: Ok, thanks butting together an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Mike Brant suggest I would consider altering your datamodel to a limit to set and creating a column for each of these in your `properties` table. But some times the boss comes: "We also need 'flatscreen tv'" and then you have to go back to the DB and update the scheme and your data access layer.

A way to move this logic somehow out if the database it to use bitwise comparison. This allows you to make simple queries, but requires a bit of preprocessing before you make your query.

Judge for yourself.

I've put everything in a test suite for you here [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06785/2)

The basic idea is that each property in your table has an id that is the power of 2. Like this:

```
INSERT INTO `advanced_options` (id, name)
VALUES
 (1, 'Wifi'),
 (2, 'Enclosing Garden'),
 (8, 'Swimming Pool'),
 (16, 'Grill');
```

You can then store a single value in your properties table buy adding up the options:

```
Wifi + Swimming Pool = 1 + 8 = 9
```

If you want to find all properties with wifi and a swimming pool you then do like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `properties` WHERE `advanced_options` & 9 = 9
```

If you just wanted swimming pool this would be it:

```
SELECT * FROM `properties` WHERE `advanced_options` & 8 = 8
```

Go try out the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06785/2)

Comment: Thats great, i had forgotten about bitwise! im going to implement this today and let you know how i get on. THANKS!

Comment: I have now implemented this into my site and it functions very well! i will consider using this more oftern!

Answer (score 0):

You really need to consider a schema change to your table.  It seems that advanced options in and of themselves don't have any properties, so instead of an `advanced_options` table that is trying to be a many-to-many JOIN table, why not just have a `property_options` table with a field for each "options". Something like this

```
|prop_id  | wifi |  swimming_pool  |  etc..
-----------------------------------
|   1     |  0   |        1        |
|   2     |  1   |        0        |
```

Here each field is a simple TINYINT field with 0/1 boolean representation.

To where you could query like:

```
SELECT * FROM properties AS p
INNER JOIN property_options AS po ON p.id = po.prop.id
WHERE wifi = 1 AND swimming_pool = 1 ....
```

Here you would just build your `WHERE` clause based on which options you are querying for.

There actually wouldn't be any need to even have a separate table, as these records would have a one-to-one relationship with the properties, so you could normalize these fields onto you properties table if you like.

Comment: Thanks for that, The only reason that i have been doing it the way that i have is so that i can add additional 'options' without having to edit the structure of the database. But im begining to think i should just do the simple thing like you have above.

Comment: There are pros and cons of both.  The biggest con is that you end up with queries like this.  I think the pros (table maintenance) outweigh the cons.

Comment: @AlainCollins Absolutely correct. It really depends on how frequently you might be adding new options as to what approach is best.  Personally, for me , I think a NoSQL approach might be best if you have a list of properties that might have any number of different attributes that may even be specific to an individual property.

Answer (score 0):

Join back to the advanced_options table multiple times.  Here's a sample with 2 (lather, rinse, repeat).

```
select o1.prop_id
from advanced_options o1
inner join advanced_options o2 on o1.prop_id = o2.prop_id and o2.name = "WiFi"
where o1.name = 'Within 2 miles of sea or river'
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this?:

```
select p.*,count(a.prop_id) as cnt
from properties p
inner join advanced_options a on a.prop_id = p.id
where a.name in ('Enclosed garden','Swimming pool')
group by p.name
having cnt = 2
```

That query would get all the properties that have ALL of those advanced_options...

I would also suggest normalizing your tables by creating a separate table Called `Advanced_option (id,name)` where you store your unique Option values and then create a junction entity table like `Property_x_AdvancedOption (fk_PropertyID, FK_AdvancedOptionID)` that way you use less resources and avoid data integrity issues.